# When transaction's blockTime is null?

Tags: transactions, rpc, jsonrpc-api, transaction, block-time

Documentation says, that transaction's blocktime can be null "if not available" - what are these cases when "not available"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be for blocks before the end of 2020, before block time was included. I think this PR added it: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/11955